# How to remove dots after the chapters numbers?

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I would like to remove the dot that appears just after chapter's title. 
[image]

How could I do that? This is my mwe using TeXShop Version 3.75 :

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
                   twoside=semi,%
                   headings=small,%
                   chapterprefix=true,%
                   listof=flat]%
    {scrbook}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{pdfpages} 

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%numéros page%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% See scrguien.pdf, chapter 5
    \ihead{\headmark}% running head at the inner edge of the page head
    \ohead*{\pagemark}% page number at the outer edge of the page head (plain pages too)
    \ofoot*{}% no page number at the outer edge of the page footer (plain pages too)
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
    \addtokomafont{part}{\scshape\LARGE}
    \addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\Huge}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\scshape\large}
    \addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
    \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\itshape}
    \addtokomafont{paragraph}{\scshape\small}
    \addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\scshape\small}
    %\let\bfseries\mdseries

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage [french]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{chngcntr}
    \counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%Numérotation des chapitres et section%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents


    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum

    \mainmatter

    \part{Objet et méthode}

    \chapter{Définitions}
    \lipsum
    \end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your code, I don't get any dots after the `chapter`-level headers. Which TeX distribution do you employ?

Comment: Off-topic: Do not use package `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: I get your dot after the chapter number only using the option "numbers=enddot".

Comment: @esd: Why? I already wrote my thesis using that package. I just want to remove the dot after the title number.

Comment: With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you will get a warning regarding `tocloft`. It breaks KOMA-Script features. Note, that your code does not produce a dot after the chapter number. Do you have also Roman numerals or letters as chapter numbers? Maybe in an appendix?

Comment: I modified my mwe.

Comment: in the title and text of your question, you say you want to remove the dot after the chapter *title*.  In a comment, you say you want to remove the dor after the *number*.  Which is it?  If appropriate, please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the dot only after chapter numbers in the chapter title redefine `\chapterformat`¹:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter
  \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%numéros page%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% See scrguien.pdf, chapter 5
\ihead{\headmark}% running head at the inner edge of the page head
\ohead*{\pagemark}% page number at the outer edge of the page head (plain pages too)
\ofoot*{}% no page number at the outer edge of the page footer (plain pages too)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{part}{\scshape\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\Huge}
\addtokomafont{section}{\scshape\large}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\itshape}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\scshape\small}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\scshape\small}
%\let\bfseries\mdseries

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% can be removed with an uptodate TeX distribution
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}% can be removed with an uptodate TeX distribution
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter%\autodot
  \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\mainmatter

\part{Objet et méthode}

\chapter{Définitions}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

¹ To remove the final dot after all numbers (chapter, section, ..., figure, table) use class option `numbers=noenddot`.